# HTTPS certificate error while running ASP.Net Core application in docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, azure-devops

I have created an ASP.Net Core application and compiled it using a YAML Pipeline. I am publishing the output in docker image and pushed in Azure Container Registry.
The endpoint URL for the application is https . But I am getting below error when I try to run the container locally.

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Below is the Docker file content. In the YAM pipeline I have published the compiled result in Output folder.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base

EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:8080
FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./Output/ /app
RUN ls

RUN addgroup --group t--gid 2000 \
&& adduser \
--uid 1000 \
--gid 2000 \
"tst"
RUN chown tst:tstgr /app
USER tst:tstgr

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testsite.dll"]
```

Here is the code for

```
 public static ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            try
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

                services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, (OpenIdConnectOptions options) =>
                {                    
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;


                });

                
                var redisConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CacheConnection");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redisConnectionString))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"App setting RTC:CacheConnection is either empty or missing");
                }

                _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();                
                services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                }).AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
                
                // Add the Kendo UI services to the services container.
                services.AddKendo();
                services.AddRazorPages();
                services.AddScoped<ICacheService, CacheService>();
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            // Configure Kendo UI
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Ins",
                pattern: "Ins/{*Manage}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ins", action = "Manage" });
            });s
        }
        private async static Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext ctx)
        {
            var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            const string AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE = @"https://graph.windows.net/";
            var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);
            
            string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var cache = new adowebhub.Controllers.RedisTokenCache(ctx.Options.ClientId, userId);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri), credential, resource: AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE);
            ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
        }
```

It seems like I need to attach a certificate to make it run but I am unclear on how to do that. When I run the application without docker it works fine.
Please suggest.

Comment: You need a certificate for https, have you tried adding one as suggested in the error message? `dotnet dev-certs https` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`? Add it manually inside the container or in the dockerfile instruction before the app lauch.